# Import new contacts and campaign members together

Tags: data-loader, campaign-member, data-import-wizard, data-import

I have a CSV file that includes contact's first name, last name, and email address. The file also includes campaign names. These contacts do not exist in the Salesforce. Is it possible to add these contacts to Salesforce and also add them as campaign members in one go?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without writing automation using [flows](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_after-save_trigger.htm&type=5&release=226) or [Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm) in Salesforce.